# Disabled field in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have one field = **"Service Tag"**, but this field has to be disabled when a user is filling in the request form and mandatory for Admin when status is to be changed from `Pc Arrived` to `Scheduled for Setup`. And also the status has 5 attribute which is :

1. Pc Pending
2. Pc Order
3. Pc Arrived
4. Scheduled for Setup
5. Completed.

So how can I disabled that field? Is it that possible to do?

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a JS library for this.

[Lozzi.Fields.js](https://github.com/DavidLozzi/SharePoint-HideDisableFields)

Comment: Insert Script editor/content editor web part to list form, and then insert the script to the web part. Check this sample https://youtu.be/s0YaOE8Byv4 ,  replace the hyperlink with JavaScript Script shared by library author.